# Python ValueError: too many values to unpack in class

Tags: python, valueerror

So when I try to run some tests for this code, it run into 'ValurError: too many values to unpack (expected 3)'

Can someone look at it and try to fix this?

Appreciate for your help.

```
class BookDict:
    def __init__(self, filename):
        self.my_dict = {}
        with open(filename) as f:
            for line in f:
                title, author, ratings = line.strip().split(",")
                ratings = [float(rating) for rating in ratings.split(";")]
                self.my_dict[title] = Book(author, title, ratings)

    def lookup(self, title_string_some):
        if title_string_some in self.my_dict:
            book = self.my_dict[title_string_some]
            print(f"{book} ({book.average_rating():.2f})")
            return book
        else:
            print("Not Found")
            return None
```

Test code:

```
my_bookdict = BookDict('books2.csv')
my_book = my_bookdict.lookup('Pride and Prejudice')
book2 = my_bookdict.lookup('Erehwon')
```

Comment: `title, author, ratings = line.strip().split(",")` this line may be creating this issue which means that when you are splitting your line into three elements then you are getting less elements as compared to required which in your case is 3

Answer (score 0):

As Deepak has already pointed out, your error probably occurs because `line.strip().split(",")` does not return a list of three elements that you can unpack correctly.

```
# working example
line = "a,b,c"
# line.strip().split(",") == ['a', 'b', 'c']
title, author, ratings = line.strip().split(",")
```

If line only has two values, that does not work:

```
line = "a,b"
# line.strip().split(",") == ['a', 'b']
```

You need to identify which value is missing.

If for example ratings is missing, you can unpack your list using a star like this.

```
title, author, *ratings = line.strip().split(",")
```

ratings == 'c' in the first example and [] in the second.

An alternative is to check the length each time.